# Input that can handle multiple arguments

Tags: python

I am trying to set the names of multiple players in a `for` loop however I am having difficulty with this as input only accepts a single string as an argument. What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
for i in range(len(game)):
    game[i].set_name(input("Player ", i, ": "))
```

Where `game` is an array of objects. I am wondering if there is a way to do this in a one liner.

Comment: its not clear what your question is....

Comment: Essentially I want the users to prompted with `Player 1: `, `Player 2: ` on the commandline but I can't do that because `input` only takes a single string argument for instance I can do `Player: `, `Player: `. My above code gives the error `input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want format strings i think

```
input("Player {player_num}: ".format(player_num=i))
```

if you really want it to behave like print i guess you could do something like

```
def my_input(*args):
    return input(" ".join(map(str,args)))
```

but that really doesnt make much sense to do

Comment: Yes something like that is what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to concatenate the elements as a single string?

```
for i in range(len(game)):
    game[i].set_name(input("Player " + str(i) + ": "))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is already solved, but I will give a different Idea:

Why dont you let the player insert the names of all players, and ask him to separate them with a space.

You would have a string,
with the comand

```
var.split()
```

you would have the list of names to be used, by the order they gave them.
you can also sen params to split to usa commas or semicolons as separators